# Is there a model browser window for LINQ to SQL?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm looking for a way to list the tables/objects in a **LINQ to SQL** model, and search them, similar to the Model Browser window for Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a work-around, I'm editing the *.dbml file directly. However, this seems much more error prone (copy-paste errors, requires more knowledge of framework, etc.), for repetitive changes.

**UPDATE (and actual fix):**
I had to install SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) for my specific version of Visual Studio. This doesn't have to match your target version of SQL Server.
See here for Visual Studio 2017:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017

Note that using the standalone installer did NOT work for this purpose (LINQ to SQL model browser). Only using the Visual Studio installer, and after a restart did the browser load.

*I didn't update this answer immediately, so there may be something I'm missing; please add more detail if you encounter this issue.*

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MS SQL Server? If so you should be able to use the Database Diagrams.

Comment: (In SQL Server, I mean.)

Comment: Are you saying changes can be imported to the model (dbml) from the database? Yes, SQL Server is being used.

Comment: For EF, are you using "code-first" or "database-first"?

Comment: ^It's not EF; it's LINQ-to-SQL (effectively the precursor to EF).

Comment: Maybe the "method pane" as per this post? https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/using-linq-to-sql-part-1

Comment: ^Similar, but for the tables. | 
I'll wait a few more days for answers.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that in Visual Studio 2017 the model browser can be activated by pressing Ctrl+1 if the edmx diagram is displayed at the same time.

Comment: In my case there was no edmx. It was dbml.